# How To Create Directory in Android 11

Tags: android, directory, subdirectory, android-11

I want to create a Directory in android 11 and save a PDF file in it.

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

this tag only works in android 10 but not working in android 11.Here is the image of error [image]

Comment: Requesting legacy external storage only makes sense for an Android 10 device.

Comment: Creating directories is like you used to do it. But not on all places. You did not tell where. In which directory. Better show your code. Dont use images to give us info. Post text only.

Answer (score 0):

You have limited access to public directories. You can check from [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) which folder you can read and write data on And 10-11.

You can also do whatever you want in internal storage. I mean you can create folder on your own application folder.